# Getting wrong Json formatted Object from servlet

Tags: jquery, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

I working on a spring hibernate project. I am trying to fetch the data in the form of Json object and populate the Drop down list base on that Json Data. I am using ajax jquery call, but in return I am only getting [object object] [object object]... I debug the jquery in google developer console and I am getting the error (the json object contain tow field brandID and BrandName)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (AddItem:51)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
success @ AddItem:51
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
A @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
```

Here is the jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ItemCategory').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type       : 'post',
            url        : "${home}/Admin/AddItem",
            data       : {dropdown: $('#ItemCategory').find(":selected").val()},
            datatype   : 'html',
            success    : function(responseText)
            {
                $('#BrandList').empty().append($('<option>').val('-1').text('select brand..'));
                $.each(JSON.parse(responseText),function(index,element){
                    $('#BrandList').append($('<option>',{value:element.BrandID,text:element.BrandName}));
                });
                $('#BrandList').selectpicker('refresh');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

servlet code

```
    public String getbrand(String catid){
        List<BrandLoader> list = brand_Service.getItemBrand(catid);
        json = null;
        json = gson.toJson(list);
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(json);/* output see below */
        return json;
    }
```

I am getting correct json but still the same problem

```
[{"BrandID":"brand-21","BrandName":"HTC"},{"BrandID":"brand-22","BrandName":"Sony"},{"BrandID":"brand-23","BrandName":"Lenovo"},{"BrandID":"brand-24","BrandName":"Micromax"},{"BrandID":"brand-25","BrandName":"Panasonic"},{"BrandID":"brand-26","BrandName":"Vivo"}]
```

Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="brand")
public class BrandLoader {

    @Id
    private String BrandID;

    @Column(name="brandname")
    private String BrandName;

    @Column(name="cat_id")
    private transient String Cat_ID;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id :"+BrandID+" brand_name :"+BrandName;
    }

    public String getBrandID() {
        return BrandID;
    }

    public void setBrandID(String brandID) {
        BrandID = brandID;
    }

    public String getBrandName() {
        return BrandName;
    }

    public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        BrandName = brandName;
    }

    public String getCat_ID() {
        return Cat_ID;
    }

    public void setCat_ID(String cat_ID) {
        Cat_ID = cat_ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your Entity class if you are using hibernate

Comment: 1. It would be `dataType` (with an uppercase `T` in `Type`) and 2. why `'html'` if you're returning JSON?

Comment: @Andreas the above jquery code working fine with another Json object same code

Comment: Just because `dataType` is misspelled